# R: Categorizing column dependent on value in another column (same characters exist)

Tags: r, grepl

I'm sure there's a painfully easy solution to this, but given I'm new to R I'm a bit stumped.

I have a large dataset with the data structured accordingly.

```
  v1 
1  US2  
2  L1_US24  
3  US2_0   
4  US24
5  US245
6  US245
7  US24 L
8  US3
```

What I'd like to do is create a categorisation column dependent upon the values in v1 like so:

```
  v1          Cat 
1  US2         1  
2  L1_US24     2  
3  US2_0       1  
4  US24        2  
5  US245       3  
6  US245       3
7  US24 L      2
8  US3         4
```

Now if it was a binary choice it would be quite easy for I could use 'grepl' with 'ifelse' to assign the values accordingly. However I'm unsure whether that is an efficient way of doing it in a large dataset where the same values are contained in the columns.

Can anyone provide some advice on how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Hi alec22, just a little remark: I guess that `Cat` number should be `4` and not `5` for `US3` (i.e. last line ). Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find a more general solution that should answer the different cases you encounter.

## **Reprex**

### Solution with `Base R` only

- Code

```r
# Extract codes 'USXXX'
code <- regmatches(df$V1, regexpr("US\\d+", df$V1))

# Convert codes into numeric categories and add the in the 'Cat' column
df$Cat <- as.numeric(factor(code, levels = unique(code)))
```

- Output

```r
df
#>        V1 Cat
#> 1     US2   1
#> 2 L1_US24   2
#> 3   US2_0   1
#> 4    US24   2
#> 5   US245   3
#> 6   US245   3
#> 7  US24 L   2
#> 8     US3   4
```

### Solution using `stringr`

- Code

```r
# Extract codes 'USXXX'
code <- stringr::str_extract(df$V1, "US\\d+")

# Convert codes into numeric categories and add them in the 'Cat' column
df$Cat <- as.numeric(factor(code, levels = unique(code)))
```

- Output

```
df
#>        V1 Cat
#> 1     US2   1
#> 2 L1_US24   2
#> 3   US2_0   1
#> 4    US24   2
#> 5   US245   3
#> 6   US245   3
#> 7  US24 L   2
#> 8     US3   4
```

- Data

```r
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("US2", "L1_US24", "US2_0", "US24", "US245", "US245", "US24 L", "US3"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for this. One question, if I wanted to change the category to a specific character or phrase instead of a number, how would I achieve that?

Comment: @alec22, I'm afraid it is difficult to answer in absolute terms: there are so many cases that can be considered. Anyway, in the simplest case if you want to change the numbers, say by "XZ" to have "USXZ" codes, you just have to change `"US\\d+"` by `"USXZ"` and it should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @alec22, if this answer meets your needs, please consider marking it as validated and/or upvoted to make it easier for other SO users to find the right answers. Cheers.

Comment: Ahh apologies, I was afk.

Comment: No worries @alec22 and thank you very much for your feedback. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to factor and then to numeric:

```r
df$Cat <- as.numeric(factor(df$v1, levels = unique(df$v1)))

df
     v1 Cat
1   US2   1
2  US24   2
3   US2   1
4  US24   2
5 US245   3
6 US245   3
7 US243   4
8   US3   5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this. Is there a way of doing it by checking to see if a particular set of string pattern is contained in the column? Namely if it contains "US2" put in category 1, but if it contains "US24" put in category 2. Unfortunately simply counting the number of digits won't work.

Comment: How many levels do you have? you could do it manually.

Comment: It's quite a large dataset (thousands of values) which grows quite regularly. Sometimes new categories need to be created (but I can do that manually), but I need to populate this categorisation column.

Comment: tell me what you think of the edited answer?